# Selecting option from a list with 2 matching noded in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am quite new to selenium testing

I need to select one of the element "Sign up" from dropdown list but when I do so `that element not visible` is displayed by Webdriver.

I think the reason is that the xpath `.//*[@id='li_myaccount']/a` which I give to find element displays 2 matching nodes in the firepath

I tried with Select option but the webdriver throwed exception `expecting select but was li` 
Can anyone let me know how to select element from dropdown form List which does not have select id but has List Id ???

Please find attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPEni.png) for details.

Comment: is Sign Up appearing by clicking on MY ACCOUNT or by moving mouse onto MY ACCOUNT?

Answer (score 0):

If you search first the UL element then later you can find elements inside

```
getDriver().findElement(By.className("dropdown-menu")).findElements(By.tagName("li")).get(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

If SignUp and Login are getting listed on click of MyAccount, you have to click My Account first and then use //*[@id='li_myaccount']/ul/li[2]/a to click